# OpenLDAP cn=config database access blocked

Tags: openldap, sasl, slapd

I use OpenLDAP 2.4.54 with Alpine. Here is my ldap configuration

```
$ sudo slapcat -n0
dn: olcDatabase={-1}frontend,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcFrontendConfig
olcDatabase: {-1}frontend
structuralObjectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
entryUUID: afb8286a-68e7-426d-8a9f-91f52935c4af
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20200807074746Z
entryCSN: 20200807074746.355242Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20200807074746Z

dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
olcDatabase: {0}config
olcAccess: {0}to *  by * none
olcAddContentAcl: TRUE
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcMaxDerefDepth: 15
olcReadOnly: FALSE
olcRootDN: cn=config
olcSyncUseSubentry: FALSE
olcMonitoring: FALSE
structuralObjectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
entryUUID: 570fed11-408d-42a2-bf96-3e063cc8276e
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20200807074746Z
entryCSN: 20200807074746.355548Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20200807074746Z

dn: olcDatabase={1}mdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcMdbConfig
olcDatabase: {1}mdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/openldap/openldap-data
olcSuffix: dc=mydomain,dc=tld
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=mydomain,dc=tld
olcRootPW:: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq
structuralObjectClass: olcMdbConfig
entryUUID: 5e4e308d-3243-4dd0-aa45-d289eb5575ab
creatorsName: cn=config
createTimestamp: 20200807074746Z
entryCSN: 20200807074746.355490Z#000000#000#000000
modifiersName: cn=config
modifyTimestamp: 20200807074746Z
```

I cannot edit the cn=config database with a SASL auth:

```
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f anything.ldif
SASL/EXTERNAL authentication started
SASL username: gidNumber=1000+uidNumber=1000,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth
SASL SSF: 0
modifying entry "cn=config"
ldap_modify: Insufficient access (50)
```

I cannot use the root dn `cn=config` to authenticate:

```
ldapmodify -H ldapi:/// -D cn=config -f anything.ldif
ldap_bind: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
    additional info: unauthenticated bind (DN with no password) disallowed
```

Now. How can I edit anything in this database now that it seems I do not have any rights on this? I could try to give access to `gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth` with `olcAccess`, or add a `olcRootPW` for `cn=config` but I do not have accesses to do this.

How can i solve this is a chicken and egg problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if it is a good practice, but I could solve this by manually adding a `olcRootPW` in `/etc/openldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={0}config.ldif`